# DAE with delay implementation in NDSolve and in SystemModeler

Tags: differential-equations

Following Code was simulated easy in Wolfram System Modeler.
But how to implement this equation in `NDSolve`?
Mathematica code:

```
sol = NDSolve[{v'[t] + a[t] - b[t - 1] == 0, v[t] == a[t] + b[t - 1], 
    b[t] == -a[t - 1]/3, a[t /; t < 0] == 0, b[t /; t < 0] == 0, 
    v[t /; t < 0] == 0, WhenEvent[t > 1, v[t] -> 1]}, {a, b, v}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Gives:
Error test failure at t == 1.9999999999999432`; unable to continue. >>
System Modeler solver gives:
[image: SystemModeler results:]

Comment: Please display your code in Mathematica format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{v'[t] + a[t] - b[t - 1] == 0, 
    v[t] == a[t] + b[t - 1], b[t] == -a[t - 1]/3, a[t /; t < 0] == 0, 
    b[t /; t < 0] == 0, v[t /; t < 0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[t > 1, v[t] -> 1]}, {a[t], b[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "MassMatrix"}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.025];
Plot[Evaluate[sol], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]